# Table view cells lose their data when leaving view using navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I have a table view which has custom cells. My table view cell get populated through the values inserted in an SQLite database.

The database values are shown in my table view cells, but the problem is, when I navigate from my table view to the previous view, and back to the tableview through the navigation bar, the table view becomes empty. What might be the problem?

Comment: How are you navigating back and forth. There seems to be a problem of table view reuse. You need to populate the tableview based on the current view you are in.

Comment: HI @Praveen ,i am navigating back by using the back navigation button and again naviagting forth by using pushviewcontroller on navigationController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edited to suggest a more likely solution based on comments to this answer***

Assuming you're adding the login view as a modal viewController, you need to refresh the table after each additional login. In your `viewWillAppear` method reload your tableView:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Or, if your table takes a while to reload, you can send a notification to the viewController to reload the tableView from the login view before you dismiss it.

---

<s>Currently-not-visible views can be unloaded at-will by the OS if memory gets tight. A common iOS development mistake is to assume that the code in a viewController's `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidUnload` methods will only be called when the view is first loaded and later unloaded. Check to make sure that your `viewDidLoad` method isn't making any assumptions about the availability of data and that your `viewDidUnload` method isn't accidentally deleting data that the newly re-called `viewDidLoad` will need.</s>

Similarly, ensure that your `viewWillAppear` method isn't being thwarted by something in your `viewDidUnload` method.

Lastly, and in the same vein, understand that if your view gets dumped by the OS for memory reasons, it will sometimes call your `viewDidUnload` method as it clears it out, but sometimes seems to not call it, perhaps because the memory used by the view was so great that a failure to clear things out in its `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method made it decide to just dump the view immediately and completely, without really allowing it to clean itself up.

Comment: i have not done any code in view didunload method of my controller

Comment: @Rani Ok, did you understand my other suggestions? Does your `viewDidLoad` expect certain data to be in place that is no longer available? Is there some unexpected state change that make the `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` methods in the viewController with the table in it fail? Also, it could be that the `viewDidUnload` method in your table's viewController *should* have code in it, something that resets an application state.

Comment: i have a login controller when user enters his username and password and click on the submit button the table view fetches the data from the database and presents the data but the problem is when i click on the left navigation bar item on the navigation ans pop back again to my login controller and enter credentials and click on submit button the tableview is empty.What may be the problem

Comment: @Rani Which method loads the table cell data in your viewController with the table? `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: Hi @Frederick, viewDidLoad method loads the table cell data in the viewcontroller